# Update SQL record from Excel

Tags: sql

I am trying to build a quotation sheet for our sales staff. I need to read a field from a SQL record, use that quote number for the spreadsheet, add one to it, and then update the SQL record to the incremented number.

Reading the data is easy, pushing an update to a single field in a specific record is the hard part.

Anyone done this before?

Some of you have suggested ways of exporting to CSV, and then importing. That is not what I am looking to do here. What I want is an interactive spreadsheet that retrieves, and then dynamically updates the SQL table record. I need this to require ***no*** user interaction.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Hi David - welcome to SO! Browse around looking for other QAs like yours. Don't forget to update/edit your question & accept an answer if it helped you.

Comment: Something has to start the process, there has to be some kind of interaction to tell it to 'GO'.

Comment: While this question should have been closed, it is not even a dupe of what it's linked to.

Answer (score 2):

export the data from excel as a CSV. Then create a temporary table with it and use that to get the info you need and then export that information to your "real" table.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp LIKE real_table;

LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.csv'
INTO TABLE temp
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(list, values, here); 

UPDATE real_table
INNER JOIN temp on temp.id = temp.id
SET real_table.value = temp.value;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temp;
```

Comment: Sorry, but that is not what I am looking for. I need this to be interactive, allowing the user to click on a macro link, and have it automatically update a single field, in a single record of a table in a SQL database. The table is dedicated to just holding the last quote number.

Comment: this is exactly what you need. This is the SQL command to do what you want. SQL is not "interactive" you need to build a front end if you want to do that, your question didn't indicate any other programming knowlage, you aren't going to find what you are looking for if you don't ask exactally what it is you are looking for. maybe next time try "I am trying to write an interface in *Programing Language* to interactively allow users to upload excel files to SQL."